# using hue to increment a checkpoint counter java

Tags: java, hue

I am creating a racing game using java and have got a checkpoint counter and a lap counter. I have drawn lines on the track to increment the checkpoint counter. When the checkpoint counter reaches 9 and they pass over the blue line the lap counter then increments. The problem is that when the car goes over a line the checkpoint counter or the lap counter will either keep incrementing or it will not move at all.

```
Player player;
float scaleFactor, translateX, translateY;
color c;
int counterlap=0;
int countercheck=0;
void setup() { 
size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
frame.setResizable(true); //make the screen adjustable
background=loadImage("track.png");
player =  new Player(100, 100); //initialize the player object
scaleFactor = 2;
} 

PImage background; //define an image for the background
void draw() {
  background(0);
  imageMode(CORNER);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  scale(scaleFactor);
  translate(-width/2, -height/2);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(-player.position.x+width/2, -player.position.y+height/2);
  image(background, 0, 0, background.width, background.height); //draw background
  popMatrix();
  popMatrix();
  c = get(width/2, height/2);
  println(hue(c));
  player.draw(); //draws the player
  text("Laps "+counterlap, width-50, 20);//lapcounter
  if (countercheck>=9) { 
    if  ((hue(c)>135)&&(hue(c)<141)) {
      counterlap++;
      if ((counterlap>=1)&&(countercheck>=9)) {
        countercheck=0;
      }
    }
  }  
  text("Checkpoint "+countercheck+"/9", width-200, 20);//checkpoint counter
  if ((hue(c)>249)&&(hue(c)<254)) {
    countercheck++;
  }
}
class Player { //creates the player class for the player object
  PVector position, velocity; //defines position & velocity vectors
  float vel, accel, heading; //scalar magnitudes
  PImage car;
  Player(float xposition, float yposition) {
    position = new PVector(xposition, yposition); //initialize everything and pass the spawn point
    velocity = new PVector(0, 0);
    accel=0;
    car = loadImage("car.png"); //loads the image for the player
  }
  void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(width/2, height/2); //translates car origin to the position vector
    scale(scaleFactor);
    rotate(heading+PI); //rotates to the current heading
    imageMode(CENTER); //centers the car image for better rotation
    tint(color(255, 0, 255)); //colour of the car
    image(car, 0, 0, 64, 40); //draws the image and resizes to 64x40
    noTint(); //disable tint for remainder of frame
    popMatrix();
    if (up) { //acclerate when up is pressed
      accel=0.15;
    } else { //otherwise no accleration
      accel=0;
    }
    if (down) { //brake/reverse
      accel=-0.15;
    }
    if (left) {
      heading-=0.04*sqrt(abs(vel)); //
    }
    if (right) {
      heading+=0.04*sqrt(abs(vel));
    }
    if (!(up||down||left||right)) {
    }
    vel+=accel;
    velocity=PVector.fromAngle(heading);
    velocity.setMag(vel);
    if (hue(c)==97.48252) {
      vel*=0.9;
    } else {
      vel*=0.99;
    }
    velocity.limit(50);
    position.add(velocity);
    if (position.x>background.width) {
      position.x=background.width;
      velocity.x*=-0.1;
    }
    if (position.x<0) {
      position.x=0;
      velocity.x*=-0.1;
    }
    if (position.y>background.height) {
      position.y=background.height;
      velocity.y*=-0.1;
    }
    if (position.y<0) {
      position.y=0;
      velocity.y*=-0.1;
    }
  }
}
boolean up, down, left, right;

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent e)
{
  scaleFactor *= pow(2, e.getAmount() /10F);

  translateX -= e.getAmount() * mouseX / 100;

  translateY -= e.getAmount() * mouseY / 100;
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    up = true;
    text("D", width-500, 20);
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    down = true;
    text("R", width-500, 20);
  }
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    left = true;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    right = true;
  }
  if (key == 'r')
  {
    scaleFactor = 2;

    translateX = 0;

    translateY = 0;
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    up = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    down = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    left = false;
  }
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    right = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the current approach:

- If your player stays **on** the line, for each frame he stays there, you will count a lap.
- If your player passes quickly from a point on **one side** the lap line to another point on **the other side**... he has crossed the line, but if there was no intermediate frame when he stood right on top, you will not count a lap.

To fix this, instead of looking at "where is the player in this frame", you should check "has the player moved, in this last frame, from being on one side of the line to being on top or on the other side of the line; -- and has he done the same for all N checkpoint lines before doing so". Since this can happen only once, and exactly once for each lap, you will now count the number of laps correctly.

This means that you cannot rely on hue alone; unless you make sure that, no matter the speed of the car, it is impossible to trigger "from one side to the other without ever being right on top" in a single frame.